# DirectX stretched pixels

Tags: c++, directx, resolution, directx-11, pixel

I am just starting off with directX and have run into a problem with stretched pixels. When I create the window and all the directX goodies I use two variables, width and height. For most testing I have them set to 800x600. When I draw a square on the screen it looks stretched. 
[image: Res of 800x600]

However when I set the resoltion to 600x600
[image: Res of 600x600]

it looks normal and square. This led me to conclude that it was some sort of pixel stretching. In directX how do I fix this, and make the pixels square.

Comment: Two questions: 1) how do you create your projection matrix, 2) are you recreating your back buffer on resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float aspectRatio = bufferWidth / bufferHeight;
```

That is completely normal. Once you project into normalized screen space, coordinates go from -1.0 to 1.0 (left to right) and -1.0 to 1.0 (bottom to top). You can see that both directions on the screen have the same range of values. This means that if you draw a square on the screen with equal height and width, it will be **aspectRatio** times greater in width than height. This explains the good behaviour at 600x600 but a problem at 800x600.(**aspectRatio** of 1.33)

If you really want a square, what you can do is simply divide the width by your aspect ratio which in your case is `800/600` (1.33) to get a polygon of equal width and height.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set your viewport according to your window size.

For example:

```
// Setup the viewport for rendering.
viewport.Width = (float)screenWidth;
viewport.Height = (float)screenHeight;
viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;

// Create the viewport.
m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
```

You can check on [Rastertek Tutorials](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut03.html) for more details.